# Ransack Gem Search String has no comma but search field value contains one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, ransack

I am currently using the Ransack Gem to do searches in my rails app.  However, I have locations that should be searchable by name.  The problem comes into play when a user searches for "Effingham IL" instead of "Effingham, IL" they do not get any results in the first case but get one result in the second.  Is there a good way to make ransack split strings to search strings containing all the values?

Thanks

```
<%= f.text_field :name_cont, placeholder:"name" %>
```

Comment: Add the search condition here.

Comment: @Bharatsoni is that what you were looking for?

Comment: No the searching hash for the ransack gem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check whether your string has ',' in it and search

**controller:**

```
if !params[:q].nil?
   if !params[:q][:name_cont].include?(',')
    params[:q][:name_cont] = params[:q][:name_cont].insert(params[:q][:name_cont].rindex(' '), ',')
   end
 end
```